# How to draw only this part of the arc?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, geometry, geometric-arc

Take a look at this picture:

[image]

I know p1, p2, and center, which are 2d points.
I also know the angle p1-center-p2 and the radius r.

How can I draw only the filled part of the arc using the canvas' function arc()?

**EDIT**

What I really need to do is, given 2 points and an angle, draw a curved line between these 2 points such that p1-center-p2 angle is the given angle.

What I do is calculate the center and the radius of the circunference that has those 2 points in it and now I need to draw the line that joins p1 and p2 and has the given angle.
This is my function to calculate the center of the circunference (which works properly)

```
function getCenter(v0x, v0y, v1x, v1y, curve) {
    // result = p0
    resx = parseFloat(v0x);
    resy = parseFloat(v0y);

    // tmpvec = (p1 - p0) * .5
    tmpx = (v1x - v0x) / 2;
    tmpy = (v1y - v0y) / 2;

    // result += tmpvec
    resx = resx + tmpx;
    resy = resy + tmpy;

    // rotate 90 tmpvec
    tmptmpx = tmpx;
    tmptmpy = tmpy;
    tmpy = -tmptmpx;
    tmpx = tmptmpy;

    // tmpvec *= 1/tan(c/2)
    tmpx *= 1/Math.tan(curve/2);
    tmpy *= 1/Math.tan(curve/2);

    // return res + tmpvec
    return [resx+tmpx, resy+tmpy];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [atan2(y,x)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) is helpful for calculating the angle to points in a circle.

```
function drawArcPart(cx, cy, radius, p1x, p1y, angle) {

    var x = p1x - cx;
    var y = p1y - cy;

    var startAngle = Math.atan2(y,x);
    var endAngle = startAngle - angle;

    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle='black';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, startAngle, endAngle, true);
    ctx.fill();
}
```

[image]

I have uploaded this JavaScript to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BSwhf/8), with an extension that also draws the points, and both your examples.

Comment: But I have other things drawn which I don't want to delete

Comment: What I really need is something like:
moveTo(p1)
arcTo(p2, radius)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working when p1 has a different x component than p2: http://i.imgur.com/AKpgv.png

Comment: Sure:
p1 = (100,100)
p2 = (100,300)
center = (200,200)
radius = 100 * sqrt(2)

Another:
p1 = (100,100)
p2 = (150,300)
center = (225,175)
radius = 145.77

I can provide you a function that calculates the center and the radius given 2 points and an angle (it's what I'm using)

Comment: Btw, I edited the main post to fully explain what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @Ivan: Thanks for the examples. See my new solution using `Math.atan2(y,x)`. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: +1 for the pretty pictures and editing the question tags to be more appropriate (even if it might have been a 'bump' edit, it was appropriate ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<html>
    <head></head>
<body onload="drawShape();">
<div>
    <canvas id="tutorial" width="150" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
function drawShape(){
    // get the canvas element using the DOM
    var canvas = document.getElementById('tutorial');
    // Make sure we don't execute when canvas isn't supported
    if (canvas.getContext){
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.beginPath();
        var x          = 100;               // x coordinate
        var y          = 100;               // y coordinate
        var radius     = 100;                    // Arc radius
        var startAngle = (Math.PI)-((Math.PI)/4);                     // Starting point on circle
        var endAngle   = (Math.PI)+((Math.PI)/4); // End point on circle
        ctx.arc(x,y,radius,startAngle,endAngle, false);    
        ctx.fill();
    } else {
        alert('You need Safari or Firefox 1.5+ to see this demo.');
    }
}
</SCRIPT>
</body>
</html>
```

It is a modified example from [mozilla HTML5 tuts](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes#Arcs)

And the result is [here](http://pastebin.me/49661d54b56f063fd3858d575a007da4)

Is this what you want?